# Can not install a Java web application on Fedora

Tags: fedora, software-installation, java

In company I use a licensed enterprise web app written in Java. So far I used it only on Windows. Not long ago I was able to install it on Ubuntu as well. Recently I discovered Fedora . And i try to move all my stuff on this distribution, including work stuff. When I try to install that app on Fedora, I get such an error :

[image]

Comment: Start the program with `java -Djava.awt.headless=true yourprogram.jar`

Comment: its an installation file. with extension ".sh".

Comment: can you edit this `.sh` an look for where it can be the `java` execution? other option is to export an empty display environment variable BEFORE you execute it:   `export DISPLAY=""`  then run your `.sh` script

Comment: Latter did not work. And when i open .sh file with gedit it gets locked.

Comment: Maybe using the `JAVA_OPTS` environment variable BEFORE runing the script?  `JAVA_OPTS="-Djava.awt.headless=true"` and then run your script... These are all the possibilities to make your software run Headless and not try to open a display as it seems to be doing on your error report...

Comment: it did not work either.

Comment: Then, is better for you to open a request on your software support if neither of these options worked..

Comment: On Ubuntu I just did these instructions : http://i.imgur.com/vVlZMbI.png

Comment: Probably it works on only Debian distributions.

Comment: It's an X11 error, so you'll either need to a) turn off Java's use of X11 b) make X11-from-root work or c) login as root to an X11 session. The `chmod 777 *` instructions from the install guide do not inspire any sort of confidence in the quality of this software, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a Wayand problem. So, I clicked the gear on the login screen, after I have clicked my username. Then I selected "Gnome on Xorg" option. Finally I provided my password and it started Xorg session. Installation worked.